# Problems with Catkin Metapackages

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been hashing through a build of Groovy on a BeagleBone. I've finally figured out there are issues with some of the metapackages that are causing my builds to fail.

WARNING: Metapackage "driver_common" must build_tool depend on catkin
WARNING: Metapackage "geometry" must build_tool depend on catkin

What do I need to do to correct this issue and get these metapackages to make? (and why are these packages faulty and not corrected at the source??)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62150/problems-with-catkin-metapackages/) by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on ROS Answers with karma: 160 on 2013-05-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Those are only warnings in Groovy, they will not cause the meta packages not to build.

In Hydro they will be errors and it will cause the build process to fail.

They have not been fixed in upstream because that would require a release of those upstream repositories into groovy, which we try not to do unless there is a good reason.

No action should be required to have this work in Groovy, if the build is failing it is for another reason.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on 2013-05-05**:
Okay, I will dig some more. It is the packages that give this warning that are not building.

**Comment by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on 2013-05-05**:
The failure happens when I run rosdep after adding these metapackages into the src directory (rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro groovy -y). I get "Unable to locate package..." errors like: Unable to locate package ros-groovy-diagnostic-updater. Why?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-05-06**:
See: http://answers.ros.org/question/61715/rosdep-gives-wrong-home-brew-packages-on-osx/?answer=61762#post-id-61762

**Comment by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on 2013-05-06**:
Good to see the link. It makes more sense now and knowing how early in this new enviroment things seem to be.